# Building app on Xcode 4.3 gives icon warning

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am building app on Xcode 4.3 it given error in  icon dimension as i am using 76*76 because client want to deploy this for iOS  and in xcode it gives warning icon dimension does not meet the size requirement it should be 72*72 pixels.

Any idea how to remove this warning.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get warnings if your icons are not the proper size.  The icons for ios need to be the following sizes:

72x72 Home screen on iPad

144x144 Home screen for iPad with retina display

57x57 App Store and Home screen on iPhone/iPod touch

114x114 Home screen for iPhone with retina display

120x120 Home screen for iPhone running iOS 7

Here are some helpful links for you to look at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/08/15/new-metrics-for-ios-7-app-icons